# gnuplot assign color to column and reuse color for bar an legend in newhistogram from previous histogram

Tags: gnuplot

I want to set the color of the key (legend) set linetype (lt) and linecolor (lc) entries to match the color to use for plotting, but also to reuse the color for column 23 to 44 = for [i=23:*] for the same 'equipment' from column 2 to 22 = for [i=1:22]

Input:

```
| week             | A | B  | C | D  | E  | F  | G | H | I | J | K | L | M  | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T  | U  | V  | W  | A | B  | C | D  | E  | F  | G | H | I | J | K | L | M  | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T  | U  | V  | W |
|------------------|---|----|---|----|----|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|----|----|----|----|---|----|---|----|----|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|----|---|---|---|---|---|---|----|----|----|---|
| 2023-41 (Oct-09) | 1 | 21 | 3 | 35 | 0  | 26 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 44 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 7  | 46 | 31 | 2  | 0 | 5  | 1 | 10 | 0  | 26 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5  | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5  | 7  | 4  | 2 |
| 2023-42 (Oct-16) | 0 | 13 | 1 | 15 | 11 | 25 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 72 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 40 | 22 | 9  | 0 | 5  | 1 | 9  | 5  | 9  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 3  | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 12 | 12 | 3  | 2 |
| 2023-43 (Oct-23) | 0 | 13 | 2 | 21 | 1  | 38 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 38 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 3  | 33 | 26 | 7  | 0 | 11 | 2 | 8  | 1  | 4  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 5  | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3  | 15 | 0  | 2 |
| 2023-44 (Oct-30) | 0 | 18 | 2 | 19 | 2  | 33 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 54 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 4  | 36 | 21 | 5  | 0 | 10 | 1 | 9  | 4  | 19 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0  | 20 | 2  | 5 |
| 2023-45 (Nov-06) | 0 | 13 | 2 | 17 | 1  | 35 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 45 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 8  | 30 | 47 | 4  | 0 | 6  | 1 | 8  | 1  | 17 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2  | 7  | 2  | 2 |
| 2023-46 (Nov-13) | 0 | 19 | 4 | 36 | 1  | 45 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 38 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7  | 29 | 28 | 3  | 0 | 9  | 1 | 25 | 0  | 15 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 6  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1  | 6  | 1  | 7 |
| 2023-47 (Nov-20) | 0 | 16 | 1 | 18 | 1  | 39 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 18 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 11 | 23 | 22 | 5  | 0 | 10 | 0 | 10 | 5  | 17 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 8  | 5 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2  | 4  | 1  | 4 |
| 2023-48 (Nov-27) | 0 | 4  | 5 | 25 | 1  | 48 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 0 | 21 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4  | 35 | 29 | 3  | 0 | 7  | 0 | 14 | 1  | 23 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 5  | 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 4  | 4  | 1  | 5 |
| 2023-49 (Dec-04) | 0 | 12 | 2 | 14 | 1  | 51 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 52 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7  | 28 | 32 | 8  | 0 | 5  | 0 | 8  | 14 | 23 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 6  | 12 | 2  | 4 |
| 2023-50 (Dec-11) | 0 | 7  | 0 | 18 | 1  | 35 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 35 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5  | 32 | 14 | 6  | 0 | 5  | 0 | 8  | 9  | 14 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4  | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0  | 9  | 1  | 2 |
| 2023-51 (Dec-18) | 1 | 8  | 4 | 18 | 0  | 61 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 52 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4  | 36 | 20 | 5  | 0 | 6  | 0 | 6  | 8  | 19 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3  | 9  | 1  | 1 |
| 2023-52 (Dec-25) | 1 | 15 | 3 | 13 | 2  | 44 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 54 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 7  | 49 | 15 | 11 | 0 | 7  | 0 | 10 | 2  | 34 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 11 | 10 | 8  | 3 |
| 2024-01 (Jan-01) | 0 | 13 | 8 | 23 | 0  | 47 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 33 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 4  | 27 | 39 | 13 | 0 | 4  | 0 | 6  | 8  | 18 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 11 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2  | 13 | 10 | 2 |
| 2024-02 (Jan-08) | 0 | 20 | 2 | 22 | 1  | 54 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 7 | 1 | 0 | 33 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 7  | 23 | 25 | 7  | 0 | 6  | 2 | 6  | 15 | 11 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4  | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1  | 8  | 3  | 6 |
| 2024-03 (Jan-15) | 0 | 14 | 4 | 10 | 0  | 15 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 54 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 7  | 50 | 13 | 2  | 1 | 7  | 1 | 13 | 16 | 13 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2  | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2  | 8  | 6  | 1 |
```

Script:

```
set datafile separator ","

# Define Legend at the bottom
set key bmargin center horizontal Left reverse noenhanced autotitle columnhead nobox

# Configure the histogram style
set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.9 relative

# Function to convert ISO week number to a date
calendar_date(w) = strptime("%Y-%W", w)

# Configure x-axis labels to display month and year
set xtics rotate by 45 right
set timefmt "%Y-%W"
set format x "%b\n%Y"

# Set axis labels
set xlabel "Week"
set ylabel "Usage"

# Define line colors and match key text colors
set linetype 1 lc rgb "0xffa07a"
set linetype 2 lc rgb "0x708090"
set linetype 3 lc rgb "0x2e8b57"
set linetype 4 lc rgb "0x87ceeb"
set linetype 5 lc rgb "0xbebebe"
set linetype 6 lc rgb "0x8b4789"
set linetype 7 lc rgb "0x9400d3"
set linetype 8 lc rgb "0x556b2f"
set linetype 9 lc rgb "0xda70d6"
set linetype 10 lc rgb "0x8d5524"
set linetype 11 lc rgb "0x228b22"
set linetype 12 lc rgb "0xffa500"
set linetype 13 lc rgb "0xffa07a"
set linetype 14 lc rgb "0x666666"
set linetype 15 lc rgb "0x008000"
set linetype 16 lc rgb "0xee82ee"
set linetype 17 lc rgb "0x9400d3"
set linetype 18 lc rgb "0x000080"
set linetype 19 lc rgb "0x0000ff"
set linetype 20 lc rgb "0xffff00"
set linetype 21 lc rgb "0xf0fff0"
set linetype 22 lc rgb "0x333333"


# Match key text color with the linetype color
set key textcolor lt 1


# Plot the data with colors for Equipment Team A + B
plot newhistogram "\n Equipment Team A", \
     'destructionrate_by_type_per_week.csv' using 2:xtic(1) title columnheader(2) lt 1, \
     for [i=2:22] '' using i title columnheader lt i, \
     newhistogram "\n Equimpent Team B", \
     '' using 23:xtic(1) notitle lt 1, \
     for [i=23:*] '' using i notitle lt (i-23)
```

output:
[image: The colors of the bars/Columns on the right sight do not match the bars/columns on the left side.]

Comment: What is your column separator? comma or `|`? Please provide your correct .csv data.

Comment: Comma. (set datafile separator ",")

Comment: The data you provided has | in it.

Comment: @sdf your current data and script does not produce the given graph! Please give a [minimal, complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Furthermore, your data doesn't have 44 columns.

Comment: Question can't be changed. Please delete and I will ask again with the requested changes.

Comment: Why can't the question be changed? There is an [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77874587/edit) below the question. You should also be able to delete your own question.